# How can i get Boost DLLs into CMake install directory?

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I have a CMake build that depends on the Boost C++ Libraries, the dependencies are manged via vcpgk.
The CMakeLists.txt looks something like this

```
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS filesystem locale)
[...]
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} 
    PRIVATE
        MyOtherSharedLibrary
        Boost::headers 
        Boost::filesystem 
        Boost::locale
)
```

After a build on Windows I can then find my binary and the associated Boost DLL files  in the `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR`.

**How can I write an CMake `install` command so that the Boost DLL files will end up in the install folder on Windows?**

Of course that should work platform independent, I use the vcpkg default triplets on all platforms and therefore on Linux the Boost libraries are statically linked.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up installing the files with the `install(DIRECTORY)` command. Using a wildcard allows to do a version agnostic install.

```
if(WIN32)
install(DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}/ 
    TYPE BIN 
    FILES_MATCHING 
    PATTERN "boost_filesystem*.dll"
    PATTERN "boost_locale*.dll"
    PATTERN "boost_thread*.dll"
    PATTERN "boost_program_options*.dll"
    PATTERN "boost_timer*.dll"
    PATTERN "boost_chrono*.dll"
)
endif()
```